# How to remove Non-English characters in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, non-english

I have been trying to remove rows that have non-english words in Postgresql. However, it does not seem working. This is my current code and sample data:

```
Select
translationid,
medium
from translation
where medium like '%[^A-Z,a-z]%'
```

[image]

Comment: Those *"English"* characters are in fact Latin

Comment: how do i extract it in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regular expression match with the `~` operator:

```
WHERE NOT meduim ~ '[^A-Za-z]'
```

You might want to add other characters like space or `-` to the list in the brackets.

Comment: i still can see the non-english characters

Comment: If you want to *exclude* all entries with non-english characters, add a `NOT` - I'll update the answer.